# java Jdatechooser default month

Tags: java, jdatechooser

I have a JDateChooser and I set a range of dates. If the range is in an another month than the current the JDateChooser open by default on the current month...
If I use setDate() and give a date in the range it's works but I would like than the textfield stay empty at the opening.

Anybody know how do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the object, pass a true to the constructor. This will cause it to appear empty initially.

```
JDateChooser datefield = new JDateChooser(true);
```

[Source](http://www.se.rit.edu/~sal/uitutorials/uitot/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.html#JDateChooser(boolean))

Comment: I use the latest release and there is no constructor with boolean in 1.4 version.